# Any amazing Wordpress MultiSite sites?

Tags: customization

I'm just curious, because I love wordpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

visit for demos

http://wpmu.org/

Comment: Or most other theme sellers for that matter. [WooThemes](http://www.woothemes.com/) too, for example. They use sub-directory based multisite setup for their demo themes e.g. `http://demo.woothemes.com/canvas`.

Answer (score 1):

[The Next Web](http://thenextweb.com) is a good example of large-scale, high(ish) traffic MU site. Well implemented with a good design.

**EDIT:** As agreed upon in the comments (and quite evident from the site itself), TNW has switched from WordPress Multisite to a single site setup.

Comment: The site you posted is using Wordpress in a single-site install as it looks like.

Comment: Sorry has changed since the time of posting

Answer (score 1):

1. [WordPress.com](http://wordpress.com/)
2. [Edublogs.org](http://edublogs.org/)
3. [blog.com](http://blog.com)
4. [Blogetery.com](http://blogetery.com)
5. [Blogsome.com](http://blogsome.com)

Comment: Any non-blogging sites?

Comment: No. I'm not aware of any non-blogging sites

Comment: I meant any sites not specifically for the sole purpose of giving users their own blog. So for something that doesn't focus on proving a "blogging service". Anything like that? Maybe some type of social network?

Answer (score 1):

I think, to be blunt our own site is working very well and looks pretty good. The url is http://bloggersdelight.dk - Currently arround 10.000 blogs and around 15mill pageview / month.

Setup is scaled and balanced using several servers.